# Why docker mounts the volumes as root even though the users match?

Tags: linux, docker, podman

**In the container:**

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker run --rm -it -u 1000:1000 \
  -v /home/mark/.cache/go-build:/tmp/go-build-cache:delegated \
  argocd-test-tools:latest \
  bash -c "id ; ls -l /tmp/go-build-cache | head -2"

mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
total 3356
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 May 11 16:05 00
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

**On the host:**

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ id ; ls -l /home/mark/.cache/go-build | head -2
uid=1000(mark) gid=1000(mark) groups=1000(mark),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),117(netdev),1001(docker)
total 3356
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 16384 May 11 12:05 00
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

As far as I understand docker should mount the volume as the user, since the uids match.

Finally, my docker is a podman wrapper:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ cat /usr/bin/docker
#!/bin/sh
[ -f /etc/containers/nodocker ] || \
echo "Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg." >&2
exec /usr/bin/podman "$@"
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

And I am running WSL2 on Windows.

What is wrong? How can I mount the volume as uid 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here - https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/2898

Turns out there is a podman specific flag `--userns`. When passed a special value `keep-id` it fixes the issue:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker run --rm -it -u 1000:1000 -v /home/mark/.cache/go-build:/tmp/go-build-cache:delegated --userns keep-id argocd-test-tools:latest bash -c "id ; ls -l /tmp/go-build-cache | head -2"
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
total 3356
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 16384 May 11 16:05 00
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```